# Help with editing a png photo, I need to change the colour

Tags: image, adobe, png, editing, colors

I have a logo that needs to be changed to a pantone colour but the only way I could change the colour was if I live traced it but I lost some detail. So I was wondering if there is another way I can do this in any of the adobe software programs without losing any of the quality.
Thanks

With the website listed below I was able to change the colour but I need the image to be a spot colour not process and it still recognizes it as a process colour even though I changed it to a pantone colour.

Comment: this is the wrong place to ask such question...you can try SuperUser..

Comment: Or perhaps http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://digital-photography-school.com/changing-color-in-photoshop